# How can I use the members of a Color object

Tags: java

I have two classes. Color.java and Light.java, I'm trying to use the Color members in the Light class. without using any other attributes in the Light class(I need to have only the two below.)
i wrote for the Color class a toString method, getters and setters . and a copy constructor.
i just didnt wrote it here .
this is an exercise . and i cant use extends or any other private members in Light.
weird exercise.(they didnt write i cant use extend. they just didnt said anything about it)

```
 public class Color
 {
  private int red;
  private int green;
  private int blue;

    public Color(){
     red = 0;
     green = 0;
     blue = 0;
    }
  }
```

and I have the Light class

```
public class Light
{
   private Color color1;   
   private boolean switchedon;

  public Light(int red, int green, int blue){
     //dont know what to write here . how can i use the members of the Color class here ? without using extends. and without adding another attributes.
  }
}
```

Comment: The question should be, "how can I use the members of a `Color` **object**"?  And to answer that, you first need to answer, "what `Color` object?"

Comment: i wrote setters and getters and a copy constructor. just didnt past it . though it will be too long.

Answer (score 4):

## You could...

Change `Color` to have another constructor that takes the color values

```
public class Color
{
    private int red;
    private int green;
    private int blue;

    public Color(){
        red = 0;
        green = 0;
        blue = 0;
    }

    public Color(int red, int green, int blue) {
        this.red = red;
        this.green = green;
        this.blue = blue;
    }
}
```

## You could

Provide setters (and getters) to change the properties...

```
public class Color
{
    private int red;
    private int green;
    private int blue;

    public Color(){
        red = 0;
        green = 0;
        blue = 0;
    }

    public void setRed(int red) {
        this.red = red;
    }

    public void setGreen(int green) {
        this.green = green;
    }

    public void setBlue(int blue) {
        this.blue = blue;
    }

    public void getRed() {
        return red;
    }

    // Other getters for green and blue...
}
```

## You could...

Do both...

## You could...

Extend `Light` from `Color`, but you would still need to either provide a constructor and/or getters and setters in`Color`

Comment: actually i did everything you said i just didnt past it here .
in the Light class. i cant use extends. and ineed to initialize the 
int red, gree and blue parameters to something. 
and i cant do this without creating private members for Light.

Comment: So that leads to...what's the question then?

Comment: i have the light class. i need to initialize this parameters
(int red. int green , int blue)
how can i do this . without extending . or create new private members.
i can use this.red = red from the Color class. they're private.

Comment: Basically, you can't unless `Color` has methods or constructors to do it.  Since you already have `color1` why can't you create an instance of `Color` and assign it to `color1`?

Comment: Wow, I must not have slept well last night.  You could pass an instance of `Color` to `Light` instead of the `red, green, blue` parameters...

Answer (score 0):

either by providing a constructor for colour and or getters and setters for the fields in colour:

```
Color(int red, int green, int blue) {
   this.red = red;
   etc....
```

Comment: yes. i did it . but how can i use it in Light without extend. 
in this exercise i cant use extend. or any other private members.

Comment: As @MadProgrammer says, you could create an instance of colour outside of Light and pass this into Lights constructor and assign it to color1.  Without seeing the actual question I am not sure I can provide anything more in depth as I am not clear on your goal